# Remove space before \reftextfaraway

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, varioref

I'm trying to change the format of `\vref` output (from the [`varioref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package). I've added:

```
% Change the format of vrefs
\renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{, page~\pageref{#1}}
```

This is close, but not close enough: I end up with "1.1 , page 34". I'd like to have "1.1, page 34". Can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

try

```
\renewcommand*\reftextfaraway[1]{\unskip, page~\pageref{#1}}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was toying with 
\renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{\unskip, page~\pageref{#1}} just as you posted your solution.